# How to extract translation for gettext. AngularJS (quotes wrapped by single quote)

Tags: angularjs, gettext, text-extraction

This is how `gettext` extract translation:

```
<custom-tag custom-attr="{{'Edit page' | translate}}"></custom-tag>
```

but how can I extract from this:

```
<custom-tag custom-attr='"Edit page"'></custom-tag>
```

seems the bellow one is wrong:

```
<custom-tag custom-attr='"{{\'Edit page\' | translate}}"'></custom-tag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to extract text in such cases:

```
<custom-tag custom-attr='"Edit page" | translate'></custom-tag>
```